# Comminicating classes of a Markov Chain

Tags: probability, markov-chains

I was asked whether the following statement is true or false:

> "Every closed communicating class of a Markov chain is recurrent."

Is it true that this statement would only be true for a finite chain? I'm not sure where to start or if I'm missing something generally true at the moment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider asymmetric random walk on the integers.  It is irreducible so has only one closed communicating class, but it is transient.

It is true for finite Markov chains.  The proof should be in standard textbooks and is basically the pigeonhole principle.